# Using aws ssm to execute python script that takes an argument

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have a python script on an ec2 instance that I can run by sshing into it and executing as such

```
python /root/path/to/file/main.py local
```

here `local` is the argument that `main.py` takes and it runs just fine.

But I cannot get it to execute using ssm send command

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "i-0a09530abchd5eb55" --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters commands=["python /root/path/to/file/main.py local"]
```

This always results in

```
"StandardErrorContent": "  File \"/root/path/to/file/main.py\", line 33\n    def main(mode: Mode):\n                 ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\nfailed to run commands: exit status 1"
```

I have not seen any examples online where the python file takes arguments and executing the command on the box works perfectly. So not quite sure what's going on here

Comment: Do you have example of `main.py`? The error message suggests there is something wrong with the file on line 33.

Comment: hmm unfortunately its propriety code and not even written by me. Line 33 is the definition of main function which is itself wrapped in some other obfuscated code. All I know is that I am able to run it on bash. But good to know that its not ssm but maybe a quirk of the code itself

Comment: Maybe you can provide some dummy code which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Ok I’ll work on doing that. Thanks for the help